# When does angular2 @output resolve?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, angular5

Consider this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JtPOCW1QqPkEWmxtHSGA?p=preview)

HTML

```
<chart [options]="options" 
       (load)="saveGraphInstance($event.context)"></chart>
<div (click)="switchGraph()">switch</div>
<div (click)="showLoadingForce()">show loading</div>
```

Typescript

```
class AppComponent {
    constructor() { 
        this.options = {
            title : { text : 'simple chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129],
            }],
            lang:{
                loading: 'your text here',
            },
        };
    }
    options: Object;
    graph: any;

    switchGraph() {
      this.options = {
            title : { text : 'different chart' },
            series: [{
                data: [129.9, 171.5, 106.4, 129],
            }],
            lang:{
                loading: 'your text here',
            },
        };
        this.graph.showLoading() // This doesn't work
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.graph.showLoading() // This also doesn't work
        }, 4000);
    }

    showLoadingForce() {
      this.graph.showLoading() // User clicked work
    }

    saveGraphInstance(graph) {
      this.graph = graph;
      //this.graph.showLoading() // after loading work
    }
}
```

We see from the above code that in the same function that option change, `show loading` does not work even if I set time out for more than 4 second

But if its done after `load` trigger or user initiated, then it always work.

This is very interesting, so my question is the following

1. If I click `switch` div and immediately click `show loading` div, the loading text will show, then the `setimeout` will execute (because 4 sec delay), but only the `setimeout` will run into error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showLoading' of undefined`. How is that possible? If `showLoadingForce` is successful that means `saveGraphInstance` must have happened
2. When is `(load)` execute and resolve? I cannot find the relevant information in github [source code](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/blob/master/src/ChartComponent.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Q1,

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'showLoading' of undefined

This is an issue with accessing `this` inside `setTimeout()`.  Inside the setTimeout method `this` default to window object. To fix this pass the save the the reference to this then access it in setTimeout method.

Refer to [the "this" problem.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem)

Regarding Q2, load is defined as output ChartEvent binding in the ChartComponent. This will invoke new instance of EventEmitter.

Use following code to hide the loading image after setTimeout: Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJPZHWeB2lM6eY6Mkcdg?p=preview)

```
 saveGraphInstance(graph) {
      this.graph = graph;
      this.graph.showLoading();
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function(graph) {
            that.graph.hideLoading();
        }, 4000);
    }
```

[JS API Reference](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang.loading)

Comment: hmm, I already know that I can hide or show if I put it in `saveGraphInstance` , my questions is why is that happening and when is `@output` resolved

Comment: Where do you have @output in your example?

Comment: In question number `2`, I linked a github source that is the source of `load` which is link to `saveGraphInstance` in my example plunker, however I want to know the execution sequence of when `load` execute in the context of angular4 life cycle to get a better understanding of why question number 1 is happening.

Comment: @jal, You have to pass the reference of this to setTimeout method then you wouldn't get the error.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem

Comment: you are correct, it is indeed a `this` issue, and seems like `load` is a native event according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)